# ASM 32 Assignment Doubts

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, endianness

i'm having a problem understanding what exactly the processor is doing and why in my asm32 assignment

```
MOV DX,07c8
XCHG DL,DH
MOV WORD PTR Vet[93],DX
ROR BYTE PTR Vet[94],5
PUSH WORD PTR Vet[93]
POP Ris1
```

from my understanding it should go like this:

1.DX registry=07C8

2.DX=C807

3.Vet[93]=07, Vet[94]=C8

4.C8 becomes 46 so Vet[93]=07,vet[94]46

5.I push 07 then i push 46

6.I pop twice (since the size of Ris1 is 32bit) And since i gotta pop first the last pushed value i get 46 07 (hex) as a result in Ris1.

The compilator itself shows the result is indeed 46 07 h, what i am having difficult understanding is why it's 46 07h and not 07 46h... I guessed it's related to the push and pop Command, but i'm not sure...

Is it related to little Endian/big Endian or i guessed right?

thanks for your time ^^.

Comment: When you say the "compilator [*sic*] itself shows the result is indeed `46 07` h", how is it being shown? It's a word with high byte of `46` and low byte of `07`, so I would expect showing it as a 16-bit word would indeed yield `46 07`.

Comment: i debugged it and saw that the variable Ris1 value is 46 07h but what i wanna know is, is it out of it being pushed and then popped or was it cuz i understood the little endian/big endian thing wrong?

Comment: It depends upon whether your debugger is showing you a word. If in your debugger you asked to see a word value, then the value makes sense and I don't think anything tricky went on with the pushes and pops. The pushes and pops will adhere to whatever endianness applies to the processor you are using. If you push a word, it will go into memory low byte, low address on an x86. When you pop the value into the same length word, it should come out the same way it went in.

Comment: Ris1 is a Word cuz is a short int, what i don't understand if when i do     PUSH WORD PTR Vet[93] i am pushing in 07 then 46, and when i pop Ris1 I get 46 07 because of it, or there is another reason i got this result?

Comment: The word at `Vet[93]` is `4607h` viewed as a word since `07` is in the low byte and `46` is in the high byte. When you push it as a word, it will go onto the stack as `07` low, `46` high. When you pop it into `Ris1` as a word, it will be a word value of `4607h`. All very consistent. The `x86` endianness says low byte goes to low address.

Comment: Wait, maybe i got it, the moment i pop in Ris1 i'm asking for 16 bit, so i'm asking for 4 hex letter starting from the Vet[93] position, but each Vet position only hold 2 hex letters, so what i'm asking is actually the value encoded in Vet[94]Vet[93] wich is indeed 4607h (since when i mov the values i put 07 in vet[93] and c8 becoming 46 in Vet[94]) did i got it right this time? my brain is frying.

Comment: @YuriCollector'sEditionRossi One more remark: the [push] tag does not apply here (it concerns version control systems) and [pop] enforces extremely fine-grained classification of the question. I suggest to use [endianness] tag instead of these two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing your original code and your initial comments:

```
    MOV DX,07c8
```

1. DX registry = 07C8h [**yes**]

   `XCHG DL,DH`
2. DX = C807 [**yes**]

   `MOV WORD PTR Vet[93],DX`
3. Vet[93] = 07, Vet[94] = C8 [**yes, because x86 is little endian: low byte to low address**]

   `ROR BYTE PTR Vet[94],5`
4. `C8` becomes `46` so `Vet[93]` = `07`, `vet[94]` = `46` [**yes**]

   `PUSH WORD PTR Vet[93]`
5. I push `07` then i push `46` [**NO... stack goes high memory to low memory, so if you are looking at the stack a byte at a time, then `46` will be first followed by `07`; BUT... the x86 pushes a word into memory, it doesn't really push a byte at a time; memory order is due to x86 endianness**]

   `POP Ris1`
6. I pop twice (since the size of Ris1 is 32bit) And since i gotta pop first the last pushed value i get 46 07 (hex) as a result in Ris1. [**NO... `pop Ris1` pops a word off the stack. It doesn't "pop twice". It will maintain proper byte order due to x86 endianness.**]

Comment: Thanks a lot man, i finally understood where i was going wrong, i didn't really understood the whole 1word=2bytes=4hex letters thing, so i was at a loss untill you stated it... i'm ashamed that i was so dense to understand it, but i finally got it ^^

Comment: @YuriCollector'sEditionRossi no worries. Sometimes it just takes getting the right "hook" to get it and we can all stumble over the oddest little things sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it is related to ednianness. In your case the code seems to be executed on an little-endian CPU (e.g., x86 architecture). It means that the byte order of data stored in memory is opposite to the byte order of data stored in registers. It has no impact on 8-bit values, but bytes comprising 16-bit or 32-bit variables are reversed while being stored to RAM, and reversed back while being loaded to CPU.

Is is usually a transparent process which does not break the programmer's intent. But your example is tricky because the interpretation of data changes during execution:

1. `MOV WORD PTR Vet[93], DX` stores low byte in `Vet[93]` and high byte in `Vet[94]` – *C807* is stored as <kbd>07</kbd><kbd>C8</kbd> as it's a register⇄memory operation – your interpretation is correct at this point;
2. The high byte is then changed with `ROR` as a *byte value* – we get <kbd>07</kbd><kbd>46</kbd> – you're still correct;
3. Then the whole 16-bit value *4607* is pushed from memory on the stack, which is a memory⇄memory operation which does not change the byte order, so we still have <kbd>07</kbd><kbd>46</kbd>;
4. Finally, you pop the value and store it in a 16-bit variable, which again is a memory⇄memory operation not involving any byte-order changes, so you end up with <kbd>07</kbd><kbd>46</kbd> bytes in memory. But these bytes represent a 16-bit value of *4607*, because we always interpret in-memory data in the register byte order which, in turn, depends on the assumed byte-width of the value.

So indeed, you have <kbd>07</kbd><kbd>46</kbd> bytes in `Ris1`, but this encodes the *4607* value. You may later store `Ris1` in a register which will reverse the bytes to <kbd>46</kbd><kbd>07</kbd>, but the value remains *4607*.

Value byte order = Register byte order ≠ Memory byte order.

---

`PUSH`/`POP` operations have no impact here. These are atomic operations (you push *once* and pop *once*) which in your case just moves 16-bit data between memory locations (stack *is* memory).

`Ris1` has to be a 16-bit value or the stack has to be guaranteed to contain two zero bytes on top before entering the code block. Otherwise the two high bytes of a 32-bit `Ris1` would be undefined.

Comment: do you have any source wich will help me understand the 4th point of the process, i got a inch of what you are telling me but i can't really grasp the reason behind it and so i feel unsure i will be able to recognize this in my future assignment...

Comment: As for the endianness, there are technical reasons behind it – you may consult Wikipedia or look at [this article](http://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-big-and-little-endian-byte-order/) for an in-depth discussion. Then just look at the equation ending my answer. It stays, i.a., that the value interpretation doesn't change while being moved-and-shuffled  between register and memory. Your debugger shows you _the value_, not it's _memory layout_.

Comment: okay, i finally understood the equation you gave me, what i'm still missing is why from the byte order 07 46h i encode the 4607 value... that's the whole reason of my struggling, and i'm at a loss :/

Comment: Wait, maybe i got it, the moment i pop in Ris1 i'm asking for 16 bit, so i'm asking for 4 hex letter starting from the Vet[93] position, but each Vet position only hold 2 hex letter, so what i'm asking is actually the value encoded in Vet[94]Vet[93] wich is indeed 4607h (since when i mov the values i put 07 in vet[93] and c8 becoming 46 in Vet[94])
did i got it right this time? my brain is frying.

Comment: Yes, that's the correct reasoning. Hexadecimal notation is famous in Computer Science just because of this great feature – 2 hex digits always map to 1 byte (00h–FFh covers all 256 possible values). It is because the base of hexadecimal number system (16) is the fourth power of the base of binary number system (2) which, by mathematical theorem, implies a 4:1 digit mapping between hex and binary. But remember: byte order affects _bytes_ – pairs of _two hex digits_ – the order within a pair is never touched.